# layer list in android not displaying images properly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, drawable, xml-drawable

I have to make a shape like this-
[image]

For doing this, I have written code like this-

triangle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-45%"
            android:pivotY="97%"
            android:toDegrees="45" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="@color/nypd_blue" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

and rectangle like this-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/nypd_blue" />
            <padding android:left="2dp"
                android:top="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:bottom="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="@color/nypd_blue" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Together I am placing them in a xml file like this-

background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_triangle" android:id="@+id/triangle" android:gravity="top"
        android:top="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:right="0dp"
        />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_rectangle" android:gravity="bottom"
        android:height="10dp"
        />
</layer-list>
```

When I am using background .xml in my code for setting the background,the whole image is not getting displayed properly and only the rectangle part is coming. What is the problem here?

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/hours_spent_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/width_1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background">
```

Comment: Your image link seems not available.

Comment: is it available now?@LiJianixn

Comment: Http error : 503

Comment: i dont know why thta is coming

Comment: You can put your image or screenshot on stackoverflow site.

Comment: i did that only

Comment: @Aayushi Is your issue resolved? Why not use Vectors for simple shapes like this?

Comment: Yes I did it using vector only and it is resolved now! @AjilO.

Comment: Great!. Post the solution that worked for you. Might help someone

Comment: sure!will do that!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you test your code on device whose API is below 26.In fact, I don't know how to explain why `LayerDrawable` behaves differently below API 26. But I have a solution.

```
 RelativeLayout relativeLayout;// your layout
 LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable) relativeLayout.getBackground();
 drawable.setLayerInset(1, padding, padding, padding, padding);
```

"1" means index 1, in your code "1" means `@drawable/blue_rectangle` and you can set padding manually.

**Note you should convert dp to pixel.**

Comment: whyis java code needed here? can't it be done by just using the drawable?

Comment: `layer-list.xml` will be convert to `LayerDrawable`. What's your meaning `can't it be done by just using the drawable?`

Comment: there is a way of setting pading jsut through drawable. So, I thought it can be done like that too

Comment: I have explained there is a bug below Android6.0 when you set padding in `layer-list`.Why not try my solution?

Comment: sure I will! Thanks